# React-router-dom not re rendering Switch when state is change

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, react-apollo, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify, react-hook in my project. The app have some private Routes has been define below:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({render: C, props: childProps, ...rest}) => {  
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={rProps =>
                (childProps) ? (
                    <C {...rProps} {...childProps} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={`/login?redirect=${rProps.location.pathname}${
                            rProps.location.search
                            }`}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );

}
```

In App.js, we change *childProps* to define whether user is login or not. But when  *childProps* change, Switch not re rendering. What is the way to force React re rendering its Route because isAuthenticated is change but ProtectedRoute is not rerender.

```
const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad();
    }, []);


    async function onLoad() {
        try {
            let user = await Auth.currentSession();
            if (user.accessToken.payload) {
                userHasAuthenticated(user.accessToken.payload);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            if (e !== 'No current user') {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    }
.....
 const childProps = isAuthenticated;
 return (
 <ApolloProvider client={client} >
            <div className="App">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Route path='/'>
                        <div>
                            <Switch>


                                <Route path='/login' render={props => <Login {...props}/>} exact/>
                                 <ProtectedRoute
                                    exact
                                    path='/admin/:name'
                                    render={()=> <Admin  />}
                                    props={childProps}
                                />



                                <Route path='/' render={props => <User {...props} />}/>

                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </Route>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        </ApolloProvider>)
```

Comment: Where do you check for the value of `childProps` to change to do anything?

Comment: sorry. I upload old code. childProps is isAuthenticated. Initate state is null. If null, it redirect Login else render Admin Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route only renders again when you enter that URL again. You are doing a Redirect, meaning it will never have a chance to enter the same URL after authentication is complete. You should delay rendering the protected route until you have confirmed authentication:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoad() {
        try {
            let user = await Auth.currentSession();
            userHasAuthenticated(!!user.accessToken.payload);
        } catch (e) {
            if (e !== 'No current user') {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    }
    onLoad();
}, []);
...
const ProtectedRoute = ({render: C, props: childProps, ...rest}) => {  
    if (childProps === null) {
        // app still waiting authentication
        return 'Loading...';
    }

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={rProps =>
                (childProps) ? (
                    <C {...rProps} {...childProps} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={`/login?redirect=${rProps.location.pathname}${
                            rProps.location.search
                            }`}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}
```