# Protected router doesn't re-render when Redux state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, router

I'm trying to use Protected route to prevent pages visibility on not authenticated users. To do that, every time page reloaded I connecting to server to check token and see are user authenticated and on server response I updating Redux state. This works fine, but the problem appear when I try to update Protected Route component. Because of server response delay, component render first time with default state value which is `false`, but when I getting server response and updating Redux state to `true`, my component doesn't re-render

```
function ProtectedRoute(props, {component: Component, ...rest}){
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            render={props =>{
               if(props.userLoginStatus){
                    console.log('protected if')
                    return <Component {...props} />
                } else {
                    console.log('protected else')
                    return <Redirect to={{
                        pathname: '/forbidden',
                        state: {from: props.location}
                    }}
                    />
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userLoginStatus: state.userLoginReducer.userLogin
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967721/11084198) the solution is to add `if` statement to component which render loading until component gets answer from server. So I changed default action value from `false` to `null` and add `if` statement. In my code it looks like that:

```
function ProtectedRoute({component: Component, isAuth, ...rest}){

    //Whaiting until gets response from server
    if (isAuth === null) {
        return 'loading..'
    }
    
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if(isAuth){
                    console.log('protected if')
                    return <Component {...props} />
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to={{
                        pathname: '/forbidden',
                        state: {from: props.location}
                    }}
                    />
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuth: state.userLoginReducer.userLogin
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute)
```

I'm not sure is it best way do deal with this problem, but it seems solved my headache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "browserHistory" as below to redirect.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// ...
else {
       console.log('protected else')
       return browserHistory.push('/forbidden');
     }
```

Comment: it's not an answer to my question, because as I said, default state default value is `false`, that's means that it always redirecting to `'/forbidden'`, but if state update to `true`, it should allow to use protected components. The problem is that after state update to `true`' component didn't re-render and didn't see that state is `true`

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as well.

First, you need to dispatch an action that checks if the user is authenticated right after your store is rendered.

Since the authentication verification seems to be an asynchronous process, you might want to send two actions: `auth_verification_request` when the store renders first, and `auth_verification_success` when the authentication is successfully verified.

Then the updated state will be sent to your `ProtectedRoute` using `mapStateToProps` function. After that, your components should re-render after auth state update.

I'll show you some examples.

authActions.js

```
export const verifyAuth = () => {
        return ((dispatch) => {

            // auth verification requested
            dispatch({
                   type: 'VERIFY_REQUEST'
            })

            // signin request
            dispatch({
                    type: 'SIGN_IN_REQUEST'
            });

            // check if user is logged in or not
            if (logged_in) {

                // signin success
                dispatch({
                        type: 'SIGN_IN_SUCCESS'
                
                })

                // auth verification success
                dispatch({
                        type: 'VERIFY_SUCCESS'
                })
            }

            // if not logged in
            else {
                
                // auth verification rejected
                dispatch({
                        type: 'VERIFY_ERROR'
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

And your `ProtectedRoute` should look something like this:

ProtectedRoute.js

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    isAuthenticated,
    isVerifying,
    ...rest
}) => {

    return (
        <Route { ...rest }
            render={ props =>

                isVerifying ? (
                    <div />
                ) : isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component { ...props } />
                ) : (
                            <Redirect
                                to={ {
                                    pathname: 'REDIRECT_PATH',
                                    state: { from: props.location }
                                } }
                            />
                        )
            }
        />
    )
};
```

And when you use these components, make sure to pass the `isAuthenticated` and `isVerifying` variables to your `ProtectedRoute`. Like this:

Router.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
        isVerifying: state.auth.isVerifying,
    };
}




<PrivateRoute
    exact
    path='PROTECTED_PATH'
    component={ DashboardPage }
    isAuthenticated={ isAuthenticated }
    isVerifying={ isVerifying }
/>
```

If you have questions regarding my code, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand how adding another action to Redux helps to re-render? It doesn't works too.

Comment: When your actions are fired, it will make changes to your store state. Then your whole application will re-render.

Comment: ok, I'm using this logic: when application starts, he checks token status on server. Mean while whole application render. When application gets response from server that every thing ok and user are authenticated, he dispatch action and set to `true`  and according to you it should re-render whole application, but it's not. My `ProtectedRoute` component doesn't re-render